# Proving linear independence

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix and suppose $v_1, v_2, v_3 \in \mathbb{R}^n$ are nonzero vectors that satisfy:

$$
Av_1 = v_1 \\
Av_2  = 2v_2 \\
Av_3 = 3v_3 $$

Prove that $\{v_1, v_2, v_3\}$ is linearly independent. (Hint: Start by showing that $\{v_1, v_2\}$ must be linearly independent.)
I know if $A$ is non-singular,it is easy. But if $A$ is singular, I have no idea to get that.

Comment: Do you know about eigenvectors and eigenvalues?

Comment: Yes,but i do not think this question requires this technique

Comment: if matrix is singular,it means that it's columns or rows are also linear dependent,maybe you should use this fact

Comment: The eigenvectors corresponding to distinct eigenvalues are always linearly independent

Answer (score 4):

**HINTS**

1. Suppose $v_1$ and $v_2$ are linearly dependent, so that $v_1 = cv_2$.
2. What is $Av_1$? What about $A cv_2$? What about $cAv_2$?
3. Do the same idea for $v_3$ independence.